# How do I configure network setting in eclipse when my company serves proxy through.pac file?

Tags: eclipse, proxy, network-connection

Can any one help me how to configure network proxy in eclipse? 
I know how to do it with proxy which I find from chrome's LAN settings. But in my organization there is .pac file instead of proxy link and port.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] - Download the .pac file and searched for proxy URL and port. Used the same to configure network settings in eclipse.